# Функция, определяющая является ли буква гласной

Tags: c++, массивы

Написать функцию glasn, которая возвращает 1, если символ, полученный функцией в качестве аргумента, является гласной буквой русского алфавита, и ноль — в противном случае.

```
bool glasn(char n)
{

    int k = 0;

    char mas[11] = {'а', 'у', 'о', 'ы', 'и', 'э', 'я', 'ю', 'ё', 'е'};
    for (int i = 0; i < 11; i++)
    {
        if (n == mas[i])
            k++;
    }
    if (k == 1)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
```

Подскажите, что не так? В любом случае возвращает ноль.

Comment: А в отладчике вы уже смотрели? А с кодировками у вас все в порядке?

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов в main я написала setlocale(LC_ALL, "rus"). Больше ничего не делала

Comment: `if (k == 1)
        return true;
    else
        return false;`
не нужно так писать. пишите явно `return k == 1;`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Вот такой код

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

bool glasn(char n)
{

    int k = 0;

    char mas[11] = {'а', 'у', 'о', 'ы', 'и', 'э', 'я', 'ю', 'ё', 'е'};
    for (int i = 0; i < 11; i++)
    {
        if (n == mas[i])
            k++;
    }
    if (k == 1)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}

int main()
{
    char test[] = "фывапролджэ";
    for(char * c = test; *c; ++c)
        cout << *c << "  " << glasn(*c) << endl;
}
```

совершенно корректно компилируется и работает в VC++.

```
ф  0
ы  1
в  0
а  1
п  0
р  0
о  1
л  0
д  0
ж  0
э  1
```

Вероятно, вы вводите буквы с консоли? Тогда у вас скорее всего несовпадение кодировок. Копайте в этом направлении...

Comment: Вы правы. Я ввожу буквы с консоли.

Comment: Попробуйте набрать эти русские буквы в 866 кодировке, и не ставить никакие `setlocal`. Должно получиться. Вот [тут](http://файлообменник.рф/8i4mprp85yvb.html) - файл в 866 кодировке.